# Generate multiple columns of variables with `dplyr` and function in a vectorized manner

Tags: r, dplyr

Imagine for a collected questionnaire for dozens of subjects, I want to check whether the answers are correct for each question. To achieve this column-wise manipulation, I use the `mapply` function, where the vectorized pairs are columns(multiple variables) and vectors (multiple elements) respectively, see below the demo code for details. However, with such a method, I need to generate the variables manually to incorporate it into the original data frame, therefore, I wonder if there is an alternative method with which it can achieve a similar effect using the multivariate version of `mutate` function in *dplyr* packages? so it will not necessary to generate the names of the variables manually and realized it in a vectorized manner.

```
##simulated data generation with four questions
IDs<-paste0('subj',0,1:7)
Q1<-c('A','B','C','A','A','A','D')
Q2<-c('A','B','B','B','B','D','C')
Q3<-c('B','B','C','C','C','D','C')
Q4<-c('A','D','D','B','D','D','C')
vect<-data.frame(cbind(IDs,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4))

##answer for the four questions
answer<-c('A','B','C','D')

##method with mapply function
myfunc<-function(vec,value) {
  ifelse(vec==value, TRUE, FALSE)
}

newvariable<-mapply(myfunc, vect[,2:5], answer)

colnames(newvariable)<-paste0('Q',1:4,"_ans")
newvariable
vect_new1<-cbind(vect,newvariable)
vect_new1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base way using `apply`:

```
cbind(vect, `colnames<-`(t(apply(vect[-1], 1, `==`, answer)), paste0("Q", 1:4, "_Ans")))
```

---

Or using `map2`:

```
library(tidyverse)

vect %>%
  select(-IDs) %>%
  map2_dfc(answer, `==`) %>%
  set_names(~ str_c(., "_Ans")) %>%
  bind_cols(vect, .)
```

---

Or

```
vect %>%
  pivot_longer(Q1:Q4) %>%
  mutate(Ans = value == answer) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(value, Ans))
```

---

***Output***

```
#      IDs Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q1_Ans Q2_Ans Q3_Ans Q4_Ans
# 1 subj01  A  A  B  A   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
# 2 subj02  B  B  B  D  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
# 3 subj03  C  B  C  D  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 4 subj04  A  B  C  B   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
# 5 subj05  A  B  C  D   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 6 subj06  A  D  D  D   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
# 7 subj07  D  C  C  C  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

One option could be:

```
bind_cols(vect, vect %>%
           do(data.frame(sweep(select(., -1), 2, FUN = `==`, c("A", "B", "C", "D")))) %>%
           rename_all(~ paste0(., "_ans")))

     IDs Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q1_ans Q2_ans Q3_ans Q4_ans
1 subj01  A  A  B  A   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
2 subj02  B  B  B  D  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
3 subj03  C  B  C  D  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
4 subj04  A  B  C  B   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
5 subj05  A  B  C  D   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
6 subj06  A  D  D  D   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
7 subj07  D  C  C  C  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is related to the issue of standard evaluation. This can be rather tricky with `dplyr` ([see a blog post I wrote yesterday](https://linogaliana.netlify.com/post/datatable/datatable-nse/)).

With `dplyr` you will it will be rather hard because it is not very adapted to column names in string. Your problem would be more easily solved with `data.table`

First, convert your object to `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
data.table::setDT(vect)
```

Then, you just need to iterate over your answer vector (assuming they are on the good order !) and use `data.table` conditional replacement with `:=`

```r
output <- lapply(seq_len(length(answer)), function(ans) {

  vect[,c(paste0("Q",ans,"_ans")) := FALSE]
  vect[get(paste0("Q",ans)) == answer[ans], c(paste0("Q",ans,"_ans")) := TRUE]
} )
output <- output[[length(output)]]
```

The final line is because your repetitively iterating through the same dataset but returning a last. Only the output of the final iteration interests you.

The result is :

```r
output
# IDs Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q1_ans Q2_ans Q3_ans Q4_ans
# 1: subj01  A  A  B  A   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
# 2: subj02  B  B  B  D  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
# 3: subj03  C  B  C  D  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 4: subj04  A  B  C  B   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
# 5: subj05  A  B  C  D   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 6: subj06  A  D  D  D   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
# 7: subj07  D  C  C  C  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
```